# create a .msi file to install MVC .net web application with localDB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, setup-deployment

I have MVC 5.0 web application and I need to make an .msi installer or exe installer to deploy the application and the LocalDB on the client machine with a icon.

Is there a tool in VS 2015 to do this.

Thnks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to install a web server, database server and web application on client machines? You also shouldn't use LocalDB as an end-user database, it's meant for development only.

Comment: Yes I want to install web server like IIS Express and database server and web application on client machine.Just one setup file,all things are install in client machine and after instillation client just click an icon and use the application.

Comment: There is a free version of Install Shield you can use:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9